# cakephp secure link using html helper link method

Tags: php, cakephp

What's the best way in cakephp to extend the html->link function so that I can 
tell it to output a secure(https) link? 
Right now, I've added my own secure_link function to app_helpers that's basically a 
copy of the link function but adding a https to the beginning. 
But it seems like there should be a better way of overriding the html->link method so that I can specify a secure option.

http://groups.google.com/group/cake-php/browse_thread/thread/e801b31cd3db809a
I also started a thread on the google groups and someone suggested 
doing something like

```
$html->link('my account', array('base' => 'https://', 'controller' => 'users'));
```

but I couldn't get that working.

Just to add, this is what is outputted when I have the above code.

```
<a href="/users/index/base:https:/">my account</a>
```

I think there's a bug in the cake/libs/router.php on line 850. There's a keyword 'bare' and I think it should be 'base' Though changing it to base doesn't seem to fix it. 
From what I gather, it's telling it to exclude those keys that are passed in so that they don't get included as parameters. But I'm puzzled as to why it's a 'bare' keyword and the only reason I can come up with is that it's a type.

Answer (score 2):

Simply linking to the secure version of a page doesn't fully prevent access to the non-secure version, therefore a better approach might be to implement automatic https switching for the actions needed.

```
<?php
class UsersController extends AppController {

    var $components = array('Security');

    function beforeFilter() {
        $this->Security->blackHoleCallback = '_forceSecure';
        $this->Security->requireSecure();
        /**
         * It is very common to require invocation 
         * of the parent beforeFilter().
         * Your usage may have the invocation 
         * at the top instead of at the bottom.
         */
        parent::beforeFilter();
    }

    function _forceSecure() {
        $this->redirect( 'https://'.env('SERVER_NAME').env('REQUEST_URI') );
    }
}
?>
```

Using this technique you can choose which controllers/actions need secured without having to worry about prepending `https://` to every single link.

Comment: It's even better to have your server redirect insecure URLs.

Comment: I already have the security component configured like that. I just wanted to save the extra redirect for pages I know will always be secure. Also, trying to go back the other way. From https to http. Once you're redirected someone to a secure page, then the rest of the time they surf the site in secure pages when the overhead is not needed.

Comment: Yes, HTTPS traffic uses more bandwidth and is therefore slower, but you can expand on the implementation above so that it automatically switches users from HTTPS to HTTP when they leave a secured action/controller.

When a "DRY" blanket solution can be created, the act of spending time manually adjusting links seems redundant.

Since the redirect happens on the server and is barely noticed by the client, trying to avoid the redirect due to "overhead" issues sounds a bit like premature optimisation.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to override the base you have to specify also server name not just the protocol.

If the link you want to create should be `https://example.com/mysite/users/action` then `https://example.com/mysite/` is your base.

Try running this code:

```
$html->link('my account', 
    array('base' => 'https://example.com/mysite/', 'controller' => 'users'));
```

Comment: Maybe I'm doing it wrong but doesn't that defeat the purpose of link then? If you have a dev environment, then all the links will be wrong. Besides, it still doesn't work with the fully qualified url.

Answer (score 1):

In _forceSecure(), it would be better use this line to redirect:

```
$this->redirect('https://'.env('SERVER_NAME').env('REQUEST_URI'));
```

Otherwise you will lose any parameters specified in a GET request.

Answer (score 1):

The best I could come up for that is the following:

```
$html->link('my account', str_replace('http://', 'https://', $html->url('/users', true)));
```

Works perfectly.